# How can I take out the first segment of a route in rails 4 scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, url-routing

I am trying to create a scaffold called 'Pages'.

So far everything is fine but the page structure now needs to change where it currently is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/pages/the-page-name
```

What I need to do now is have this instead:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/the-page-name
```

In my routes.rb I have this:

```
resources :pages
```

This obviously maps all routes within the model to this base but I want to hide this.

Is it entirely possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments), you could do this:

```
get '*pages', to: 'pages#show', format: false
```

I would recommend you make it the very last route you have, since the Rails router matches the request with the first route, and having a wildcard early in your routes file will end up clobbering all your other routes/resources.

Comment: Kenneth Kalmer, this worked fine but when I try to access the page I get this error `Couldn't find Page without an ID` in my show in the page controller I have this `@page = Page.friendly.find(params[:id])` as I am using friendly_id gem. should it be `:title`?

Comment: The page name will be in the `pages` param (`params[:pages]`). So you should be able to go `Page.friendly.find(params[:pages])`, or just rename the glob to `'*page'` to have something more digestable

Comment: boom, thanks so much Kenneth I knew it was a simple fix that small one

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `path`

```
resources :pages, path: ''
```

Comment: ah yes I did that but I already have a route for my homepage with a different template and need to keep that as is so this did not work entirely

Comment: @Mdunbavan for your homepage you should have `root to: 'homepage#action'`